# How to rebuild template for django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In my project (based on django 1.7) I have a template:

views.py:

```
def help(request, page, anchor):
    return render(request, 'help.html')
```

help.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <TITLE>FinBox Help - {{ pagename }}</TITLE>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <link rel="icon" href="media/pic/favicon.png" type="image/png">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="media/pic/favicon.png" type="image/png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/css/docs.css" type="text/css">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function tree_toggle(event) {
                event = event || window.event
                var clickedElem = event.target || event.srcElement

                if (!hasClass(clickedElem, 'Expand')) {
                        return // click out the list
                }

                // Node, on which we've clicked
                var node = clickedElem.parentNode
                if (hasClass(node, 'ExpandLeaf')) {
                        return // click on the list
                }

                // define a new class for node
                var newClass = hasClass(node, 'ExpandOpen') ? 'ExpandClosed' : 'ExpandOpen'
                // replace the current class on newClass
                // regexp finds isolated open|close and change it to newClass
                var re =  /(^|\s)(ExpandOpen|ExpandClosed)(\s|$)/
                node.className = node.className.replace(re, '$1'+newClass+'$3')
            }


            function hasClass(elem, className) {
                    return new RegExp("(^|\\s)"+className+"(\\s|$)").test(elem.className)
            }
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            background-color: white;
            background-image: none;
            color: black;
            font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
            font-size: smaller;
            font-style: normal;
        }

           A {
            text-decoration: none;
           }
           A:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
            color: red;
           }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        {% csrf_token %}

        <div style="float:left; margin-left:310px;">
            Explanation how it works.
        </div>

        <div style="position:fixed; width:300px;">
            <div onclick="tree_toggle(arguments[0])">
                <ul class="Container">
                    <li class="IsRoot">
                        <div class="Expand">

                        </div>

                        <div class="Content">
                            Content
                        </div>

                        <ul class="Container">
                            <li class="Node ExpandClosed">
                                <div class="Expand">

                                </div>


                                <div class="Content">
                                    <a href="/help/pur/">
                                        Destination
                                    </a>
                                </div>

                                <ul class="Container">
                                    <li class="Node ExpandLeaf IsLast">
                                        <div class="Expand">

                                        </div>

                                        <div class="Content">
                                            <a href="/help/test/">
                                                тест
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                            <li class="Node ExpandLeaf IsLast">
                                <div class="Expand">

                                </div>

                                <div class="Content">
                                    <a href="/help/errors/">
                                        System Exceptions
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have to replace the:

```
<ul class="Container"></ul>
```

part with the dynamic code which has to render the directory structure:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startpath):
    print root, dirs, files
```

How better to perform it in ways of django templates? I've looked at the documentation and it looks like I need to reweite it from scratch and reduce to class based template. Is it right or is it no need to do?
http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/templates.html

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First, you should think separately about the items you want to show on the front end and how to collect them on the backend. Lets start with the latter.

It looks like you are putting together a list of sorts. It doesnt really matter how you want to prepare that list, or if its even as list (you can pass objects as well, if you like - though I wouldn't recommend doing so in general practice as you might accidentally pass to the front end something you don't mean to), as long as you do. This code is likely to be executed in your app/views.py

Once you have this list, you need to pass it to the template for it to render. Do this by passing context, in the example below called mycontext, to your template with something like:

```
 return render(request, 'help.html', context = mycontext)
```

In your template, you can now call out anything you passed via context. You may even perform for loops through this context if you would like. More details on dynamic templating here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/